# Not able to install packages w/ package control for Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext

I just installed package control for Sublime Text, and now I'm attempting to install LiveReload. Whenever I pull up the command menu, scroll down to "Package Control: Install Package", no search box opens. The menu disappears, and nothing happens. Does anyone have any idea what may be going wrong?

From the Python console:

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
  File ".\package_control\commands\install_package_command.py", line 42, in run
  File ".\package_control\package_installer.py", line 52, in make_package_list
  File ".\package_control\package_manager.py", line 337, in list_available_packages
  File ".\package_control\package_manager.py", line 284, in list_repositories
  File ".\package_control\providers\channel_provider.py", line 73, in get_repositories
  File ".\package_control\providers\channel_provider.py", line 41, in fetch_channel
  File ".\package_control\package_manager.py", line 169, in download_url
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: do you have an active internet connection?  There should be a message at the bottom left of the screen explaining whats happening.  The service does go down occasionally.  Its currently working for me however.

Comment: Hit ```Ctrl + ` ``` and look at the Python console.

Comment: how did you install Package Control? Also, are you using ST2 or ST3?

Comment: Edited w/ errors from Python console. I'm using ST2, and I do have an active internet connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got everything working. In the end I uninstalled Sublime and deleted all Sublime folders, reinsstalled, installed package manager, everything worked fine. Not a great solution but it worked.